# mongoose ReplicaSetNoPrimary error on connection to a mongodb replicaset on docker

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, mongoose, replicaset

**Hello everyone**

I am currently trying to create a mongodb replicaset with docker and connect it to an expressjs app through mongoose. 
Sadly I am getting ome errors when I'm trying to connect and I'm hoping you can help me.
I'm going to walk you through every step I took to get to this point.

Here are the versions of the software I use : 
mongo v6.0.2 
mongoose v6.9.1 
docker 20.10.12-0ubuntu4

To create the replicaset, I followed [this](https://www.sohamkamani.com/docker/mongo-replica-set/) tutorial. 
I will still give every step I took to create it and then I'll show the mongoose code.

#### Mongodb replicaset config with docker

First I created the docker network :

```
docker network create mongo-cluster
```

Then created the mongo instances

```
docker run \
-p 30001:27017 \
--name mongo1 \
--net mongo-cluster \
mongo mongod --replSet rs0

docker run \
-p 30002:27017 \
--name mongo2 \
--net mongo-cluster \
mongo mongod --replSet rs0

docker run \
-p 30003:27017 \
--name mongo3 \
--net mongo-cluster \
mongo mongod --replSet rs0
```

Then I created a configuration to initiate :

```
config = {
    "_id" : "rs0",
    "members" : [
        {"_id" : 0, "host" : "mongo1:27017"},
        {"_id" : 1, "host" : "mongo2:27017"},
        {"_id" : 2, "host" : "mongo3:27017"}
    ]
  }
rs.initiate(config) // result : ok: 1
```

And finally, I set the mongo1 node as primary :

```
db.getMongo().setReadPref()
```

#### Mongoose connect config

I tried to connect to the replicaset with this code :

```
await mongoose.connect(`mongodb://mongo1:30001,mongo2:30002,mongo3:30003/chatappdb`, {
    replicaSet: 'rs0',
    readPreference: 'primary',
    w: 'majority'
}
```

And that gives me the following error :

```
Uncaught [MongoServerSelectionError: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN mongo1] {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    servers: Map(3) {
      'mongo1:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'mongo2:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'mongo3:27017' => [ServerDescription]
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: 'rs0',
    maxElectionId: new ObjectId("7fffffff0000000000000001"),
    maxSetVersion: 1,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined,
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}
```

First I checked if the primary was really defined in the cluster with `rs.status`
Here are the results :

```
{
  set: 'rs0',
  date: ISODate("2023-02-23T23:27:05.901Z"),
  myState: 1,
  term: Long("1"),
  syncSourceHost: '',
  syncSourceId: -1,
  heartbeatIntervalMillis: Long("2000"),
  majorityVoteCount: 2,
  writeMajorityCount: 2,
  votingMembersCount: 3,
  writableVotingMembersCount: 3,
  optimes: {
    lastCommittedOpTime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1677194817, i: 1 }), t: Long("1") },
    lastCommittedWallTime: ISODate("2023-02-23T23:26:57.517Z"),
    readConcernMajorityOpTime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1677194817, i: 1 }), t: Long("1") },
    appliedOpTime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1677194817, i: 1 }), t: Long("1") },
    durableOpTime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1677194817, i: 1 }), t: Long("1") },
    lastAppliedWallTime: ISODate("2023-02-23T23:26:57.517Z"),
    lastDurableWallTime: ISODate("2023-02-23T23:26:57.517Z")
  },
  lastStableRecoveryTimestamp: Timestamp({ t: 1677194797, i: 1 }),
  electionCandidateMetrics: {
    lastElectionReason: 'electionTimeout',
    lastElectionDate: ISODate("2023-02-23T21:40:47.293Z"),
    electionTerm: Long("1"),
    lastCommittedOpTimeAtElection: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1677188435, i: 1 }), t: Long("-1") },
    lastSeenOpTimeAtElection: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1677188435, i: 1 }), t: Long("-1") },
    numVotesNeeded: 2,
    priorityAtElection: 1,
    electionTimeoutMillis: Long("10000"),
    numCatchUpOps: Long("0"),
    newTermStartDate: ISODate("2023-02-23T21:40:47.337Z"),
    wMajorityWriteAvailabilityDate: ISODate("2023-02-23T21:40:48.598Z")
  },
  members: [
    {
      _id: 0,
      name: 'mongo1:27017',
      health: 1,
      state: 1,
      stateStr: 'PRIMARY',
      uptime: 6518,
      optime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1677194817, i: 1 }), t: Long("1") },
      optimeDate: ISODate("2023-02-23T23:26:57.000Z"),
      lastAppliedWallTime: ISODate("2023-02-23T23:26:57.517Z"),
      lastDurableWallTime: ISODate("2023-02-23T23:26:57.517Z"),
      syncSourceHost: '',
      syncSourceId: -1,
      infoMessage: '',
      electionTime: Timestamp({ t: 1677188447, i: 1 }),
      electionDate: ISODate("2023-02-23T21:40:47.000Z"),
      configVersion: 1,
      configTerm: 1,
      self: true,
      lastHeartbeatMessage: ''
    },
    {
      _id: 1,
      name: 'mongo2:27017',
      health: 1,
      state: 2,
      stateStr: 'SECONDARY',
      uptime: 6389,
      optime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1677194817, i: 1 }), t: Long("1") },
      optimeDurable: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1677194817, i: 1 }), t: Long("1") },
      optimeDate: ISODate("2023-02-23T23:26:57.000Z"),
      optimeDurableDate: ISODate("2023-02-23T23:26:57.000Z"),
      lastAppliedWallTime: ISODate("2023-02-23T23:26:57.517Z"),
      lastDurableWallTime: ISODate("2023-02-23T23:26:57.517Z"),
      lastHeartbeat: ISODate("2023-02-23T23:27:05.316Z"),
      lastHeartbeatRecv: ISODate("2023-02-23T23:27:04.810Z"),
      pingMs: Long("0"),
      lastHeartbeatMessage: '',
      syncSourceHost: 'mongo1:27017',
      syncSourceId: 0,
      infoMessage: '',
      configVersion: 1,
      configTerm: 1
    },
    {
      _id: 2,
      name: 'mongo3:27017',
      health: 1,
      state: 2,
      stateStr: 'SECONDARY',
      uptime: 6389,
      optime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1677194817, i: 1 }), t: Long("1") },
      optimeDurable: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1677194817, i: 1 }), t: Long("1") },
      optimeDate: ISODate("2023-02-23T23:26:57.000Z"),
      optimeDurableDate: ISODate("2023-02-23T23:26:57.000Z"),
      lastAppliedWallTime: ISODate("2023-02-23T23:26:57.517Z"),
      lastDurableWallTime: ISODate("2023-02-23T23:26:57.517Z"),
      lastHeartbeat: ISODate("2023-02-23T23:27:05.309Z"),
      lastHeartbeatRecv: ISODate("2023-02-23T23:27:04.811Z"),
      pingMs: Long("0"),
      lastHeartbeatMessage: '',
      syncSourceHost: 'mongo1:27017',
      syncSourceId: 0,
      infoMessage: '',
      configVersion: 1,
      configTerm: 1
    }
  ],
  ok: 1,
  '$clusterTime': {
    clusterTime: Timestamp({ t: 1677194817, i: 1 }),
    signature: {
      hash: Binary(Buffer.from("0000000000000000000000000000000000000000", "hex"), 0),
      keyId: Long("0")
    }
  },
  operationTime: Timestamp({ t: 1677194817, i: 1 })
}
```

From this it seems that the primary node is defined.

I tried with MongoClient as well :

```
let newClient = new MongoClient("mongodb://mongo1:30001,mongo2:30002,mongo3:30003/chatappdb?replicaSet=rs0", { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
```

And I got the same results.

I looked a little closer to the mongodb logs that are give when you run the docker instance :

```
{"t":{"$date":"2023-02-23T23:40:30.888+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"#","uuid":"#","connectionId":92,"connectionCount":29}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-02-23T23:40:30.890+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn92","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"#","client":"conn92","doc":{"driver":{"name":"nodejs|Mongoose","version":"4.13.0"},"os":{"type":"Linux","name":"linux","architecture":"x64","version":"6.1.11-76060111-generic"},"platform":"Node.js v18.12.0, LE (unified)","version":"4.13.0|6.9.1"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-02-23T23:40:30.893+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn92","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"#","uuid":"#","connectionId":92,"connectionCount":28}}
```

I don't quite understand why the connection ends so abruptly, but you might be able to understand this better than me.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Have a nice day !

Answer (score 0):

I had same error on my first tries of using replicas in mongodb

Finally I came up with following instructions now I have no problem

```
docker run --name mongodb -d -p 27027:27027 -e MONGO_REPLICA_SET_NAME=myrs -v mongo_data:/data/db -v $(PWD)/mongod.conf:/etc/mongod.conf mongodb/mongodb-community-server:4.4.2-ubuntu2004-20230912T072223Z mongod --port 27027 --bind_ip_all --replSet myrs --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

As it is present in the command, I have a file name `mongod.conf`, this files contains only this content:

```
replication:
  replSetName: "myrs"
```

Then do these:

```
docker exec -it mongodb bash
mongo --port 27027
rs.initiate();
use admin;
db.createUser({user: "your_user",pwd: "your_password", roles: [{role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" },{ role: "readWriteAnyDatabase", db: "admin" }]});
cfg = rs.conf();
cfg.members[0].host = "127.0.0.1:27027";
rs.reconfig(cfg);
```

Now I can connect to it using following uri:

> mongodb://your_user:your_password@127.0.0.1:27027/your_db?retryWrites=true&connectTimeoutMS=2000&authSource=admin&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1